# Determine video bitrate using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, bitrate

I am trying to determine video bitrate(For transcoding) using ffmpeg command,I tried following command.

```
ffmpeg -i 28572615.wmv
```

and it produces the following output

```
    Input #0, asf, from '28572615.wmv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
  Duration: 00:02:50.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1982 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: wmv2 (WMV2 / 0x32564D57), yuv420p, 640x360, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 128 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

If I use another video

```
ffmpeg -i with_out_sound.mp4
```

then i get the following output

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'with_out_sound.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2015-04-21 05:14:57
  Duration: 00:00:27.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 500 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 622x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 311:240], 100 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-21 05:14:57
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

The point I am confuse is that should I look in Duration metadata line or Video Stream metadata line(Stream #0:0) for video bitrate?

Comment: For the 2nd file, what's the file size?

Comment: @Mulvya 2nd video file size is 1.66 MB

Comment: So both of the readings are wrong - actual bitrate is 61 kb/s. This is probably because it's a DASH segment.

Comment: [How does ffmpeg determine individual stream bitrates?](http://superuser.com/q/694062/615410) explains how the rates are determined.

Answer (score 25):

The video bitrate is displayed in the video stream info. The format  info contains the bitrate for all streams plus muxing overhead.

If the video bitrate is missing, then a dirty way to get that value is by subtracting the bitrate of all other streams from the total bitrate.

If that's not viable, run ffprobe to show packet sizes and add them together, show the stream duration and then calculate the bitrate by dividing the first number by the second.

```
$ ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v -show_entries packet=size -of compact=p=0:nk=1 video.ext | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
496797924
$ ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v -show_entries stream=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 video.mp4  # format=duration if MKV
1501.761000
$ echo 496797924/1501.761000 | bc   # B/s
330810
$ echo '496797924/1501.761000/1024' | bc   # kB/s
323
```

Of course, this is only applicable if the video stream info does not sport a bitrate and estimating the bitrate by discounting the rate of all other streams is not possible either.

Comment: Note that you do not need `nk=1` when you use `csv` as the format (instead of `compact`). Also I had to use `2>/dev/null` to not get the default header about the stream.

Answer (score 7):

*Edit: See Cliff's note below if you have an **MKV video** instead of MP4.*

The easiest way to get the bitrate of a video in proper format is to use FFMPEG's utility `ffprobe`

```
$ ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 inputvideo.mp4
```

This prints the raw bitrate value on its own so that you can easily use it in some kind of script.

Taken from here: https://write.corbpie.com/getting-video-bitrate-with-ffprobe/

Comment: it results N/A  .

Comment: Can you post the output of `$ ffprobe <your-video-here>`? It could have something to do with the format of your video. @benyamin

Comment: @rlittles I get the same; this is with a video that I encoded in h.264 CRF from a formerly lossless ffv1 video capture that I inverse telecine'd. `Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:2:2), yuv422p(tv, progressive), 720x480, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn`

Comment: That's really weird. I tested it with an old H264 video and it worked. https://i.imgur.com/D0OIFwK.png This was on Windows, but I can't imagine that it would make a difference versus Linux.

Comment: @rlittles Your command pulls bitrate from the video stream header metadata. That data is not required to be written to the stream, and MKV doesn't support it, IIRC. MKV stores that info in the container, meaning you need to replace `stream=bit_rate` with `format=bit_rate` in your example for MKV containers.

Comment: @Cliff Thank you. I was thinking in MP4 mode since that's what the original question was about but you are completely right.